# extract value of attribute in xpath

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

[image]

I'm working in the chrome dev tools console trying to get the attribute value of data-label.

```
<thead>
            <tr>
        <th id="gv-field-1-id" class="gv-field-1-id" style="width:5%;" data-label="#"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5Bid%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;#</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-date_created" class="gv-field-1-date_created" style="width:7%;" data-label="Date"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5Bdate_created%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Date</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-99.2" class="gv-field-1-99.2" data-label="County"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B99.2%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;County</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-99.1" class="gv-field-1-99.1" style="width:14%;" data-label="State"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B99.1%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;State</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-5" class="gv-field-1-5" style="width:7%;" data-label="Acres"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B5%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Acres</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-13" class="gv-field-1-13" data-label="Name"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B13%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Name</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-23" class="gv-field-1-23" style="width:8%;" data-label="Ask $"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B23%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Ask $</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-122" class="gv-field-1-122" style="width:8%;" data-label="New $"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B122%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;New $</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-123" class="gv-field-1-123" style="width:8%;" data-label="Assd $"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B123%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Assd $</span></th><th id="gv-field-1-26" class="gv-field-1-26" data-label="Eager"><span class="gv-field-label"><a href="/leads/?sort%5B26%5D=asc" data-multisort-href="/leads/" class="gv-sort gv-icon-caret-up-down"></a>&nbsp;Eager</span></th>      </tr>
</thead>
```

The closest I can get to the value (Date in this case) is

```
$x('//th[contains(@id,"gv-field")]/@data-label')
```

How can I get the attribute value here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
$x('string(//th[contains(@id,"gv-field")]/@data-label)')
```